# How to apply a design on a different screen's configuration?

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to design a one screen, but different devices displays my design differently:
[image]

Both of screen displays same layout resource, but it looks not same. Left screen has resolution 480x800, right screen is 540x960. What technology or practice I should use to achieve both screens looks like right screen?

Comment: I think making every size defined in `dp` will work. Here if you are using `sp` for texts, it will depend on user's font size too. `dp` will adapt to the pixel density of device.

Answer (score 2):

To support multiple screens we create different layouts for ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi etc. For more details please check
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: No way, I cant support all devices cause I have just two devices - 480x800 with api15 and 540x960 with api21. I'm looking for universal decision for all devices. And desirable without supporting different dencities

Answer (score 0):

P. Ilyin

If you are us normal text view or layout means just use tags link 'fill _parent and wrap content'.If you use images or icon  just slice your image like below size,this is standard sizes,If you use rectangle images, it must slice based on your screen ,below size are square type

```
48x48 (1.0x baseline) mdpi
72x72 (1.5x) for hdpi
96x96 (2.0x) for xhdpi
144x144 (3.0x) for xxhdpi and etc..,
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use
**[SDP library - a scalable size unit](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)**

An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

Comment: This decision - just a tremendous set of dimensions, library not providing any new size unit. Disguisting

Comment: @P.llyin Yes it is a set of Dimensions, But these dimensions are calculated to map various resolutions.